# How to add a security group to a VM via the nova-client

Tags: openstack, openstack-nova, novaclient, python-novaclient

I'm trying to use the OpenStack Nova client and create a script in order to launch an instance.  I was able to create a VM with a specific key but the problem is that i can't add an existing security group to that instance.

I know how to create a security group and add some rules to it using the nova client.

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 7):

After launching an instance you can add a security group to it using the CLI

```
nova add-secgroup my-special-server sec-group-3
```

See the help for more info

```
nova help add-secgroup 
usage: nova add-secgroup <server> <secgroup>

Add a Security Group to a server.

Positional arguments:
  <server>    Name or ID of server.
  <secgroup>  Name or ID of Security Group.
```

Personally I would add the security group during the boot of an instance using the `--security-groups` like below

```
nova boot --image cirros-0.3.1-x86_64-uec --flavor m1.tiny --security-groups my-sec-group
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer.
What i'm trying to do is a python script to create a VM on openstack and that's why i'm using nova client.